# Asking Dropdown fo temperature input with selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, dropdown, webautomation

**Dear All in Stackover flow,**

I need your help :
I need to handle change input of bodytemperature

Picture of Web change body temperature
[image]

I need input this body temperature with random value between 35.8 - 36.5

**This is inspect elements :**

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field BodyTemperature must be a number." data-val-range="The field BodyTemperature must be between 33 and 43." data-val-range-max="43" data-val-range-min="33" data-val-required="The BodyTemperature field is required." id="BodyTemperature" max="43" min="33" name="BodyTemperature" step="0.1" type="text" value="36.1" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="33" aria-valuemax="43" class="k-input" aria-valuenow="36.1" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;">
```

And this is my code try

```
input_value = [36.10 ,36.20 ,36.30,36.50,35.80,35.90,35.80]

value = random.choice(input_value)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,//input[@id='BodyTemperature'])).send_keys(value)
```

I hope Stackoverflow can help me

Please Help Me !!!!

Answer (score 0):

For decimal values you have to use **double**, Please try the below, I have checked it it's giving the random number between 35.8 - 36.5.

```
double min = 35.8;
double max = 36.5;
double diff = max - min;
double randomValue = min + Math.random( ) * diff;
System.out.println(String.format("%.3g%n", randomValue))
```

**Result**: Like 36.1, 36.2, 35.9

Let us know if it didn't work for you.

Comment: Iám sorry i still cant input value to the dropdown textbox

Comment: If you are unable to input value in the dropdown this could be the other issue but not the one you asked above. please show us what error you are getting?